# How to count number of distinct entries in 2d list?

Tags: python, list, count, 2d

I have a 2D list and I want to learn how to return the number of distinct entries there are in the table.

```
numbers = [[32, 12, 52, 63], [32, 64, 67, 52], [64,64,17,34], [17, 76, 98]]
```

since there are 10 numbers that are not the same I want it to return that number, how do I go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your nested list into a set and take the length of it, as below:

```
numbers = [[32, 12, 52, 63], [32, 64, 67, 52], [64,64,17,34], [17, 76, 98]]

numbers_set = set(i for j in numbers for i in j)
print(len(numbers_set)) # 10
```

[Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) are containers with no duplicate elements, this means that `set([1, 1, 2]) -> {1, 2}`. The length of the set can then be used to find the number of distinct values originally in your nested lists.

Answer (score 2):

Flatten the list in a set comprehension to remove the dups

```
print len({x for y in numbers for x in y})
10
```

Or create a set and use `set.update`:

```
s = set()

s.update(*numbers)
print len(s)
10


In [1]: numbers = [[32, 12, 52, 63], [32, 64, 67, 52], [64,64,17,34], [17, 76, 98]]

In [2]: s = set()

In [3]: s.update(*numbers)

In [4]: s
Out[4]: {12, 17, 32, 34, 52, 63, 64, 67, 76, 98}
```

[python sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the easiest way to get distinct number count

`len(set(sum(numbers, [])))`

Answer (score 0):

Given `mylist`:

```
all_words =  [item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist]
distinct_no_of_words = len(set(all_words))
```